# Error while executing python 3.7 using pyinstaller

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, pyinstaller, macos-catalina

I just learned programming and using python, I can run the code in Pycharm, but cannot create the "exe" file for mac.

Previously I download the python 3.8 and I realise that pyinstaller doesn't work with python 3.8, so I uninstall the python 3.8 and install python 3.7 for mac (catalina) and create the new project in pycharm using python 3.7

could anyone please help me with this problem?

this is some result while i run the pyisntaller

```
users@users MergedFiles % pyinstaller main.py 
44 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.0
44 INFO: Python: 3.8.5
```

this is the Base Intepreter in pycharm :

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.frameworks/versions/3.7/bin/python3
```

this is the error result of my program:

```
users@users ~ % /Users/users/PycharmProjects/MergedFiles/dist/main/main ; exit;
[576] Error loading Python lib '/Users/users/PycharmProjects/MergedFiles/dist/main/Python': dlopen: dlopen(/Users/users/PycharmProjects/MergedFiles/dist/main/Python, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/users/PycharmProjects/MergedFiles/dist/main/Python: code signature invalid for '/Users/users/PycharmProjects/MergedFiles/dist/main/Python'
```

Comment: why do you think pyinstaller doesn't work for python3.8?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question right, but it is not possible to build a windows executable on MacOS.

Comment: Yeah I agree with @MauriceMeyer I think you can only create a dist of the platform you are on, so for example if you're on macos you can't create a exe and if you're on windows you can't create a macos installer

Comment: I read on https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/
it supprt for python 3.5 - 3.7, is that correct?
I mean I want to create the standalone script on my mac, so I just need to double click the script and it automatically run my program

Comment: @rexia. According to the [GitHub page](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller#requirements-and-tested-platforms) 3.8 is supported

Comment: Ok thank you for the info and could you help me to solve my problem?